# Etiquette for asking loved one to share life story before death

Tags: research-methods, communication

This might be a bit of an odd question, but I figured that at least one or more persons here have been in the situation that I am now.

My question is as follows:

> What is the (if any) 'proper etiquette' for telling a
>   loved one that you wish to record them as they tell their life story,
>   before they die and all familial information is gone?

I am struggling with how to word it without it coming out so bluntly or being seen as a rude and/or crude question to ask. Obviously, from the standpoint of a genealogist and someone in general that loves and wants to remember their family members, recording someone would seem to be common sense. However, bringing up the subject of death or phrasing your question so that it doesn't come out as, "I know you're going to die soon, so can I record you?", can be quite the task (with respect to each personality type).

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  This is certainly an area where extreme sensitivity is important.  I think there is some great advice in the answers to the question which this appears to be a duplicate of.

Comment: Great, thanks for letting me know PolyGeo. Sorry about the duplicate!